# Auth0 in Java Spring MVC without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, auth0

I asked this question in the auth0 forums aswell but does anyone know of an example of an auth0 implementation in a java spring mvc project not using Spring Boot?

All the demo applications and inplementations I've found so far all use Spring Boot.

Thanks in advance

Edit: 2. I asked this question as well on the auth0 forums [HERE](https://auth0.com/forum/t/example-auth0-java-spring-mvc-without-boot/5469).

1-3. Due to the nature of my issue I can't really specify an exact issue as each issue I resolve brings in 2 new ones. I hope that this does not get my question closed.

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your best try 2. Links to the questions you have asked on other forums 3. Detailed problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Auth0 Spring MVC Library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-mvc) does **not** depend on Spring Boot so can readily be used as a dependency by an application that has **no** dependencies on Spring Boot either.

The `official` [Auth0 Spring MVC Sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-mvc-sample) which is used as the **Quick Start** for this library was written using Spring Boot. And for the simple reason it makes it very simple to get up and running quickly (which is a primary consideration for the Auth0 Quick Starts ;) )

There are no Spring only samples (certainly, none I authored myself) - Developer feedback to date has indicated that modifying the existing Sample to Plain Spring did not present any troubles. If you find this task a problem, please contact Auth0 Support so getting a plain Spring Sample written and published can be put on the backlog.

**Disclaimer**: I authored the Auth0 Spring libraries and samples. Feel free to drop any specific questions on the comments section here if you have trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Especially the "Developer feedback to date has indicated that modifying the existing Sample to Plain Spring did not present any troubles." made me think "If they can do it, so can I". So I powered through and managed to get everything up and running!

Comment: @Shinhidora - that is awesome well done :)  Have left a provisional answer to your other question today here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583863/java-spring-mvc-auth0-sso-not-getting-tokens-no-spring-boot  just me know there if you need assistance.